Azure Data Bricks Widget Value initialize Problem for First Time Execution
I am trying to pass database name and schema details from ADF pipeline to azure databricks notebook to use my create and drop tables but if I am trying RUN ALL first time my data bricks scripts.I am getting syntax error because of the widget variable empty. kindly find below code and advice me.
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
dbutils.widgets.text("dbname","db")
dbname= dbutils.widgets.get("dbname")
dbutils.widgets.text("dbschema","dbschema")
dbschema= dbutils.widgets.get("dbschema")

drop table IF EXISTS $dbname.$dbschema.tablename;

[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '.'.(line 2, pos 21)

The syntax error you're encountering is caused by incorrect string concatenation in your SQL statement.
I have tried the below approach:
dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
dbutils.widgets.text("dbname","db")
dbname= dbutils.widgets.get("dbname")
dbutils.widgets.text("dbschema","dbschema")
dbschema= dbutils.widgets.get("dbschema")
sql_command = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbname + "." + dbschema + ".tablename"
sql_command

Results:
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.dbschema.tablename'

In the above code concatenating the values of dbname and dbschema variables with the SQL statement.
You can then use the sql_command variable in your Databricks SQL statement to drop the table.

if we want to create table, i can use similar approach right ?

also i want to use this command in notebook as below like,

%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.dbschema.tablename

Yes, you can use a similar approach to create a table with dynamic database and schema names.

sql_command = f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {dbname}.{dbschema}.tablename"
%sql $sql_command
@Developer KE can you try this for dropping
